# Accept capitalized string input

Tags: java, string, swing, oop

I have a game program wherein the user is asked to guess the scrambled word given.

For example:
Scrambled word: loglab
Your guess:

The word is global, every time I input "GLOBAL" it says the word is incorrect. I tried to use toUpperCase but it didn't worked. How can my program be able to accept strings inputted even if it's capitalized? Below are some of my codes. I wont post it all because it's too long, but if you need more of it just inform me. Please help me with regards to this matter thank you.

StaticWordLibrary.java:

```
public boolean isCorrect(int idx, String userGuess) {
        return userGuess.equals(getWord(idx));
    }
```

WordLibrary.java:

```
public abstract boolean isCorrect(int idx, String userGuess);
```

Anagrams.java:

```
private void guessedWordActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        if (wordLibrary.isCorrect(wordIdx, guessedWord.getText())){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your answer is correct! Guess another word.","", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            getRootPane().setDefaultButton(nextTrial);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your answer is incorrect! Please try again.","", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            guessedWord.setText("");
        }

        guessedWord.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of just `equals()`

Answer (score 2):

Since the word is `"global"`(lowercase) and the input is uppercase, you should use the method `userGuess.toLowerCase()` instead of `toUpperCase()`.

Another way would be comparing with `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

Answer (score 2):

Do like this

```
public boolean isCorrect(int idx, String userGuess) {
    return userGuess.equalsIgnoreCase(getWord(idx));
}
```

or

```
public boolean isCorrect(int idx, String userGuess) {
    return userGuess.toUpperCase().equals(getWord(idx).toUpperCase());
}
```